# Unity 2D unstable FixedJoint structures

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my 2D sandbox game the main gameplay vector is building structures from physical props and items by connecting them with Fixed Joint 2d. But if structure has more than 5-6 joint and I shake it a bit the structure starts to move by itself and roll and If I shake it harder it can just starts to glitch very badly. Is there a way to make them more stable? Maybe some physics setting in project settings?

I tried tweaking some settings in Physics 2D tab in Project settings but It didn't really help.